# Remove solo symbols in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, regex, dataframe, performance

I'm trying to remove any instances of a symbol that is all by itself. I want to keep any other uses of symbols, only is the symbol is by itself. This dataframe will have a mixture of letters and numbers.

What I'm doing now which is VERY inefficient.

```
#Remove solo symbols
df = df[df[column] != '']
df = df[df[column] != '_']
df = df[df[column] != '-']
...
df = df[df[column] != '&']
```

What I'm trying to do:

```
input: ["_", "hi-my-name-is", ".", "", "Hello world", "123-333", "Stack&overflow"]
output: ["hi-my-name-is", "Hello world", "123-333", "Stack&overflow"]
```

I was thinking something along the lines of this but I'm unable to make it work with a dataframe:

```
re.sub(r'-(?!\w)|(?<!\w)-|[!@#$%^&*()_+]', '', str(df[column]))
```

Any suggestions on how I can simplify these steps so that I only remove symbols that are by themselves instead of combined with numbers or letters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with the inverse (`~`) of [`str.fullmatch`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.fullmatch.html) as mask:

```
m = ~df['column'].str.fullmatch(r'[!@#$%^&*()_+.-]?')

out = df[m]
```

Or with [`isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.isin.html):

```
m = ~df['column'].isin(set(list('!@#$%^&*()_+.')+['']))

out = df[m]
```

Output:

```
           column
1   hi-my-name-is
4     Hello world
5         123-333
6  Stack&overflow
```

Used input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'column': ["_", "hi-my-name-is", ".", "", "Hello world", "123-333", "Stack&overflow"]})
```

Comment: I used a variated 
```Symbol_removal = ~df[0].isin(set(list('-!@#$%^&*()_+.')+['']))
        df = df[Symbol_removal]``` 
and it worked great. Thank you!